# Correct way to match URL path to page name with URL routing in Go?

Tags: http, go, url-routing, httprouter

I'm making a Go website (small service), and didn't know how a 
page URL was verified as correct or not found 404. Eventually I learned that http request routers / multiplexers exist.

Example:

```
eg.com/articles/animals/Hippos-are-aquatic-and-land-dwelling    = go to page
eg.com/articles/animals/Hippos-are-typofrifjirj     = 404 not found page
```

Right now I only see one way to do this, you somehow have a list of articles the website has, and you pass it into the router somehow. How should you get that list of articles?

For a dynamic relational database site:
Do you query your database for article titles, and make that a map string?

For static files on a static website: 
you use some http fileserver dir function in the router or net/http?

If so, for the database, does that mean you have to query your database every single time a page is visited? Or do you store the list of articles in a file or something and update it each time a new article is made?

Also, I would plan to use https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it with the net/http router assuming that everything after `/articles/animals/` in the path is the id of an article:

Register the handler using a trailing slash for match on all paths with the prefix `/articles/animals/':

```
mux.HandleFunc("/articles/animals/", animalHandler)
```

In the handler, strip the `/articles/animals/` to get the id of the article. Look up the article in the database. Respond with 404 if not there.

```
func animalHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  id := strings.TrimPrefix(r.URL.Path, "/articles/animals/"))
  article, err := queryArticleByID(id) 
  if err == errNotFound {
     http.Error(w, "internal error", http.StatusNotFound)
     return
  } else if err != nil {
     log.Println(err)
     http.Error(w, "internal error", http.StatusInternalError)
  }
  ... render the article
}
```

This example assumes that the `queryArticleByID()` function queries the database and returns `errNotFound` if no article is present for the give id.

Regarding caching:  The `queryArticleByID()` can check a cache before querying the database. Any caching is independent of how routing is handled.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly the only way I could see it working, but very helpful with the code example with how you integrate it with error checking etc. I'll look more into Go caching options as well, I assume Memcached / Redis.